# How would I go about scaling a pixel array?

Tags: java, arrays, pixel

So I have this function to render tiles from an image to a pixel array. I am trying to make a new function to scale the image up from say 7*7 to 14*14

Each tile is 8*8

- xp = X position
- yp = Y position
- Tile = tile
- location color = color of pixels

I am fairly sure this would be an easy task as I think I would have to just scale the array and share bits to fill in the gaps.

Please let me know if you need any more info or if you need me to simplify the code more.

```
public void scaledRender(int xp, int yp, int tile, int colors) {
    xp -= xOffset;
    yp -= yOffset;

    int xTile = tile % 32;
    int yTile = tile / 32;
    int toffs = xTile * 8 + yTile * 8 * sheet.width;

    int ys, xs;

    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        ys = y;
        if (y + yp < 0 || y + yp >= h)
            continue;

        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            if (x + xp < 0 || x + xp >= w)
                continue;

            xs = x;
            int col = (colors >> (sheet.pixels[xs + ys * sheet.width + toffs] * 8)) & 255;

            if (col < 255)
                pixels[((x + xp) + (y + yp) * w)] = Screen.colors[col] | 0xff000000;

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

This works. Thanks to GamerJosh. I don't know if its the most efficient way of doing it but it works!

```
public void scaledRender(int xp, int yp, int tile, int colors) {
xp -= xOffset;
yp -= yOffset;

int xTile = tile % 32;
int yTile = tile / 32;
int toffs = xTile * 8 + yTile * 8 * sheet.width;

int ys, xs;

for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
    ys = y;
    if (y + yp < 0 || y + yp >= h)
        continue;

    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        if (x + xp < 0 || x + xp >= w)
            continue;

        xs = x;
        int col = (colors >> (sheet.pixels[xs + ys * sheet.width + toffs] * 8)
            if (col < 255) {
                pixels[((x + xp)*2  ) + ((y + yp)*2  ) * w ] = Screen.colors[col] | 0xff000000;
                pixels[((x + xp)*2+1) + ((y + yp)*2  ) * w ] = Screen.colors[col] | 0xff000000;
                pixels[((x + xp)*2  ) + ((y + yp)*2+1) * w ] = Screen.colors[col] | 0xff000000;
                pixels[((x + xp)*2+1) + ((y + yp)*2+1) * w ] = Screen.colors[col] | 0xff000000;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: scale every "pixel" by the ratio that you want the whole of it to scale by.

Comment: Is there an error? What (specifically) is the problem that you want help with?

Comment: @GamerJosh There is no error in the code. It currently renders each tile at the size it currently is as a tile 8*8 But I want to take that 8*8 tile and scale it up to say 16*16.

Comment: Then you're looking for an algorithm? What have you tried?  A very simple algorithm would just put each pixel into the new array twice (assuming a scale of x2, as you mentioned) per column and row--have you attempted something like that?

Comment: @GamerJosh Yes that is what i'm trying to do. So far the only thing I really tried is just setting the pixels 4 times and tried shifting the x y value. But there are still gaps in the render. It looks exploded with only every other pixel being rendered.

Comment: Typically, you'd want to work backwards, mapping from destination back to a source pixel.  Because if your scale is non-integral, or not an easy multiple, you may 'miss' pixels doing a forward mapping.  You may want to have a function that takes in the source array, plus the scale factor, then build the destination array, and fill it in working backwards with the scale factor to find the source pixel, and colour your destination that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an array of Strings, here is a code snippet showing a possible (albeit extremely basic) array up-scaling algorithm.  You should be able to modify this to your needs.

```
// Initialize array
String [][] array = {{"00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07"},
                     {"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17"},
                     {"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27"},
                     {"30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37"},
                     {"40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47"},
                     {"50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57"},
                     {"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67"},
                     {"70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77"},
                     };

// Simply output the original array so we can visually compare later
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
        System.out.print(" " + array[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

// Create a new array that is twice the size as the original array
String[][] scaledArray = new String[16][16];

// Scale the original array into the new array
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
        scaledArray[(i*2)][(j*2)] = array[i][j];
        scaledArray[(i*2) + 1][(j*2)] = array[i][j];
        scaledArray[(i*2)][(j*2) + 1] = array[i][j];
        scaledArray[(i*2) + 1][(j*2) + 1] = array[i][j];
    }
}

// Output the scaled array to see the result
System.out.println("\nSCALED: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
        System.out.print(" " + scaledArray[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

The program output is:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37
40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77

SCALED: 
 00 00 01 01 02 02 03 03 04 04 05 05 06 06 07 07
 00 00 01 01 02 02 03 03 04 04 05 05 06 06 07 07
 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17
 10 10 11 11 12 12 13 13 14 14 15 15 16 16 17 17
 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23 24 24 25 25 26 26 27 27
 20 20 21 21 22 22 23 23 24 24 25 25 26 26 27 27
 30 30 31 31 32 32 33 33 34 34 35 35 36 36 37 37
 30 30 31 31 32 32 33 33 34 34 35 35 36 36 37 37
 40 40 41 41 42 42 43 43 44 44 45 45 46 46 47 47
 40 40 41 41 42 42 43 43 44 44 45 45 46 46 47 47
 50 50 51 51 52 52 53 53 54 54 55 55 56 56 57 57
 50 50 51 51 52 52 53 53 54 54 55 55 56 56 57 57
 60 60 61 61 62 62 63 63 64 64 65 65 66 66 67 67
 60 60 61 61 62 62 63 63 64 64 65 65 66 66 67 67
 70 70 71 71 72 72 73 73 74 74 75 75 76 76 77 77
 70 70 71 71 72 72 73 73 74 74 75 75 76 76 77 77
```

Comment: I seem to remember back in my Computer Graphics days that most applications use dot products (linear algebra) and matrices to do rotation, skewing, transposing, and scaling, as all of these processes can be be represented by a matrix and the math is always repeatable, and can be easily expanded to handle 3 or more dimensions.  It was like 20yrs ago, though, so my memory might be poor.

Comment: @CodeChimp Prompted by your comment, after a little searching, I found [Kronecker Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) which (when using the appropriate secondary array size, filled with 1's) seems to produce the same result as my code snippet above.  I didn't find anything to do with the dot product, but it definitely wasn't an exhaustive search, so that doesn't mean anything more than that I just didn't find it.

Comment: Yeah, it's been a while since I was in school and had to think of these things, but that looks right.  It may not be useful, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: What if we have to scale with a disproportionate scaling factor for e.g. 8x8 into 10x12 ?